# How To Install Laravel On Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laravel, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Laravel on my Ubuntu 12.04 . I have been following a lot of tutorials usually , it is just the same steps. I managed to download and setting all requirements but I cannot figure out why when I want to excute **laravel.example.com** on the browser , the webpage showed me SERVER NOT FOUND error.. but if I put **my-ip-adress/laravel/public** the laravel welcoming page is showing from index.php

anyone can help me with this?

website I referred to - http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/

Thank you.

my laravel.example.com.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName laravel.example.com
    ServerAlias www.laravel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

my apache2.conf file:

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#    /etc/apache2/
#    |-- apache2.conf
#    |    `--  ports.conf
#    |-- mods-enabled
#    |    |-- *.load
#    |    `-- *.conf
#    |-- conf-enabled
#    |    `-- *.conf
#     `-- sites-enabled
#         `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User www-data
Group www-data

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/laravel/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
        </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/laravel>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
        </Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#    AllowOverride None
#    Require all granted
#</Directory>



<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AllowOverride All FileInfo Indexes
    AddType application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml .xul
    AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

PerlSwitches -wT
PerlConfigRequire /var/www/html/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl

 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerName 127.0.0.1

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Go to PHP's log destination. 
    cd /etc/var/log....

PHP logs it's errors there. its php_error.log do this.....
    tail -f php_error.log....

Now go to your browser and try the page again. Read what the error says in the terminal. If you don't see and error, you will need to further explain your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you miss this step

1 ) `sudo gedit /etc/hosts`

2 ) add this line to file and save
 `127.0.0.1     laravel.example.com`

after that sometimes you may get forbidden error for resolve that you have to change chmod of app/storage directory to 777

Comment: Hi . may I know where I can get app/storage directory? it seems like I cannot find that . there is app folder but there is no storage directory/files in there but inside Laravel folder, there is storage folder. any idea on that?

Comment: I ran the url but this time , the browser page shows "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe"

Comment: It's okay. It's settled ! :D I have to change the permission to all folder in Laravel because I noticed it has been restricted to root user only. I did chmod 777 and I can run Laravel now. Thank you!

Comment: ohh you fixed yourself ! I couldn't come to the stackowf

Answer (score 0):

sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
Find #Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and remove the # to un-comment this line

sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Add Virtual host

sudo gedit /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 mysite.local

Restart Xampp

Answer (score 0):

On linux mint 18.1 I have installed laravel with ease, I followed a tutorial published at codentricks.com/installing-xampp-laravel-linux which show how to install xampp, setting permission of dir using command sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs, 
Setting PHP Enviroment Variable
sudo kate /etc/environment
add :/opt/lampp/bin/php in last and save
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php

Installing composer Globally

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Better Follow instruction watch video for complete reference at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2V7offiUYQ